# Symfony2: The option "widget" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to build a form using symfony2, but I keep getting the error message 'The option "widget" does not exist ' whenever I add the widget option to specify a form field type.

I'm following the example given on the documentation there http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

here is my code that does not work.

```php
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('Name')
        ->add('Login')
        ->add('Password')//, 'text', array('widget' => 'password'))
        ->add('ConfirmPassword')//, 'text', array('widget' => 'password', 'label' =>'Confirm Password'))
        ->add('Email', 'text', array('widget' => 'email'))
        ->add('ConfirmEmail')//,'text', array('widget' => 'email', 'label' =>'Confirm Email'))    
   //...
}
```

Anyone knows why ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe, the correct way to do what you want to achieve is the following:

```
->add('Name', 'text')
->add('Login', 'text')
->add('Password', 'password')
->add('ConfirmPassword', 'password', array('label' =>'Confirm Password'))
->add('Email', 'email')
->add('ConfirmEmail', 'email')
```

The first argument of `add` method is field's `name` (it has to be unique within form). The second is `type` and it is responsible for the form taken by widget while rendering. The list of built-in types [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#built-in-field-types). The third argument is array of options. Each `type` has it's own set of possible `options`. Indeed, some of types have the `widget` option. For example [`date`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#widget) type has such option. But [`password`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/password.html) and [`email`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/email.html) types don't have such option.